# Ray-tracer loop ordering

Tags: raytracing

Tracer and found an unexpected problem. If I write the two main loops of the ray-tracer, the ones responsible for the image pixels, that way:

```
for (int y=0; y<image.getWidth(); y++) {
  for (int x=0; x<image.getHeight(); x++) {
```

I get this distorted image. (actually, facebook screws the image, somehow, even more than the real one, but the point is that the code generates multiple mirrored spheres with some kind of scanlines (that are actually smaller)

[http://s72.photobucket.com/user/john_smith140/media/zz_zps907cb287.jpeg.html?filters[user]=139318132&filters[recent]=1&sort=1&o=0](http://s72.photobucket.com/user/john_smith140/media/zz_zps907cb287.jpeg.html?filters%5Buser%5D=139318132&filters%5Brecent%5D=1&sort=1&o=0)

However if, if I make a small change, to:

```
for (int y=0; y<image.getHeight(); y++) {
  for (int x=0; x<image.getWidth(); x++) {
```

It works as a charm, as can be seen below:

[http://s72.photobucket.com/user/john_smith140/media/s_zps4e50e49f.jpeg.html?filters[user]=139318132&filters[recent]=1&sort=1&o=1](http://s72.photobucket.com/user/john_smith140/media/s_zps4e50e49f.jpeg.html?filters%5Buser%5D=139318132&filters%5Brecent%5D=1&sort=1&o=1)

The `getHeight`, `getWidth` gives me the height and width of the image.
Here is some more code that I believe might be helpful:

```
Ray viewRay = { {float(x), float(y), -1000.0f}, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}};
```

The first part is the camera location, the second it's direction
I don't know why this is happening and would appreciate any input. If any more code is necessary to evaluates the problem, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that although you're changing the order of the for-loop, you aren't changing the indices.  You should try:

```
for (int x=0; x<image.getWidth(); x++) {
  for (int y=0; y<image.getHeight(); y++) {
```

Compare that with the two snippets you posted.

Comment: It Didn't work, although the incorrect image is different from the previous incorrect ones. Here is the result: http://s72.photobucket.com/user/john_smith140/media/zzz_zps83ed0c45.jpeg.html?filters[user]=139318132&filters[recent]=1&sort=1&o=0

Comment: The loop I've posted is a pretty standard one - I can't really help without seeing more of your code.  If you can post what's inside the loop, that would be helpful for debugging this.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to answer. I will post the link to a ray-tracer that suffers the same problem that I do: http://www.scratchapixel.com/assets/Uploads/Lesson001/Source%20Code/raytracer.cpp Exchanging the loops leads to the same problem that I have. From what I understand the second code piece that I quoted constructs the image horizontally, your should construct the image vertically, column by column, instead of row by row, but both should work